# preg_replace with double slash

Tags: function, replace, preg-replace

I have a problem with preg_replace function.

How to replace text:
\\Text\\ 
to:
**Text**

My code is:

```
preg_replace("/\\/(.*?)/\\/","<s>\\1</s>", "\\test\\")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this:

```
<?php
$str1 = "\\test\\";
echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 300px;\">"
  . preg_replace('/\\\\([^\\\]+)\\\\/', "<s>\\1</s>", $str1)
  . "</textarea>";
?>
```